# Custom Truncation in NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the best way to do custom truncation in a text field? The problem I’m trying to solve is that I need to display some very long URLs in only a little space, but users are mostly only concerned about the server name and lastPathComponent.

For example, http://www.google.com/verylongname1/verylongname2/coolpicturewithveryveryveryverylongname.png

would ideally show up as http://www.google.com/…(+ the longest suffix we can fit in).

Middle truncation doesn’t do exactly what I want since it gives me something more like:
http://www.google.com/verylongname1...veryveryveryverylongname.png

The text needs to be editable too, so if I modify/ValueTransform the string itself I have to reconstruct it during edit which is probably not the cleanest possible way. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: links giving Error 404

Comment: The links are not links but the examples.